# Insert data and set foreign keys with Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-migration

I have to migrate a large amount of existing data in a Postgres DB after a schema change.

In the old schema a country attribute would be stored in the users table. Now the country attribute has been moved into a separate address table:

```
users:
  country # OLD
  address_id # NEW [1:1 relation]

addresses:
  id
  country
```

The schema is actually more complex and the address contains more than just the country. Thus, every user needs to have his own address (1:1 relation).

When migrating the data, I'm having problems setting the foreign keys in the users table after inserting the addresses:

```
INSERT INTO addresses (country) 
    SELECT country FROM users WHERE address_id IS NULL 
    RETURNING id;
```

**How do I propagate the IDs of the inserted rows and set the foreign key references in the users table?**

The only solution I could come up with so far is creating a temporary user_id column in the addresses table and then updating the the address_id:

```
UPDATE users SET address_id = a.id FROM addresses AS a 
    WHERE users.id = a.user_id;
```

However, this turned out to be extremely slow (despite using indices on both users.id and addresses.user_id).

The users table contains about 3 million rows with 300k missing an associated address.

**Is there any other way to insert derived data into one table and setting the foreign key reference to the inserted data in the other (without changing the schema itself)?**

I'm using Postgres 8.3.14.

Thanks

*I have now solved the problem by migrating the data with a Python/sqlalchemy script. It turned out to be much easier (for me) than trying the same with SQL. Still, I'd be interested if anybody knows a way to process the RETURNING result of an INSERT statement in Postgres SQL.*

Comment: This is old and you solved it. But a 1:1 relation makes no sense in this case. Shouldn't you be creating a country table instead?

Comment: An address actually contains street, city, zip code, ..., and country for every user. I just simplified it to make it more readable.

Comment: Country, zip code, city, county etc. would all have their own tables. That leaves street, number etc. Still no point in a separate table for these unless more than one address is possible for each user.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The table `users` must have some *primary key* that you did not disclose. For the purpose of this answer I will name it `users_id`.

You can solve this rather elegantly with [**data-modifying CTEs**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) introduced with PostgreSQL **9.1**:

#### `country` is unique

The whole operation is rather trivial in this case:

```sql
WITH i AS (
    INSERT INTO addresses (country) 
    SELECT country
    FROM   users
    WHERE  address_id IS NULL 
    RETURNING id, country
    )
UPDATE users u
SET    address_id = i.id
FROM   i
WHERE  i.country = u.country;
```

You mention version **8.3** in your question. Upgrade! [Postgres 8.3 has reached end of life.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Be that as it may, this is simple enough with version 8.3. You just need two statements:

```sql
INSERT INTO addresses (country) 
SELECT country
FROM   users
WHERE  address_id IS NULL;

UPDATE users u
SET    address_id = a.id
FROM   addresses a
WHERE  address_id IS NULL 
AND    a.country = u.country;
```

#### `country` is not unique

That's more challenging. You *could* just create one address and link to it multiple times. But you did mention a 1:1 relationship that rules out such a convenient solution.

```sql
WITH s AS (
    SELECT users_id, country
         , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY country) AS rn
    FROM   users
    WHERE  address_id IS NULL 
    )
    , i AS (
    INSERT INTO addresses (country) 
    SELECT country
    FROM   s
    RETURNING id, country
    )
    , r AS (
    SELECT *
         , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY country) AS rn
    FROM   i
    )
UPDATE users u
SET    address_id = r.id
FROM   r
JOIN   s USING (country, rn)    -- select exactly one id for every user
WHERE  u.users_id = s.users_id
AND    u.address_id IS NULL;
```

As there is no way to unambiguously assign exactly one `id` returned from the `INSERT` to every user in a set with identical `country`, I use the window function [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) to make them unique.

Not as straight forward with **Postgres 8.3**. One possible way:

```sql
INSERT INTO addresses (country) 
SELECT DISTINCT country -- pick just one per set of dupes
FROM   users
WHERE  address_id IS NULL;

UPDATE users u
SET    address_id = a.id
FROM   addresses a
WHERE  a.country = u.country
AND    u.address_id IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM addresses b
    WHERE  b.country = a.country
    AND    b.users_id < a.users_id
    ); -- effectively picking the smallest users_id per set of dupes
```

**Repeat this** until the last `NULL` value is gone from `users.address_id`.

Comment: Many thanks! Learnt quite a few new things from your answer. And yes, we upgraded to Postgres 9.1 in the meantime. Cheers

Comment: @Pankrat: that's good news - both, that it helped and that you could upgrade to 9.1.