# psql move data to another table leaving refference to new row

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration

So, i`m writing migration.

My goal is to:

1. Create another table, which contains all the necessary fields
2. Move existing data from the `source` table to the `dest` one. (insert data into the `dest`, then update reference in the `source`, setting the `dest_id` as `id` of the just created row in the `dest` table)
3. Delete the rows which were moved from the `source` table.

I`m having difficulties with the step 2. Any ideas?

I currently have this:

```
do $$
declare os_id bigint;
begin
    insert into order_shipments (order_id, method_id, deliver_at, barcode, sent_at, city_id, subway_id)
    select o.id, o.shipment_method_id, o.courier_deliver_at, o.barcode, o.sent_at, o.courier_city_id, o.courier_subway_id
    from orders o
    returning id into os_id;
end
$$;

update orders as o set current_shipment_id = os_id;
```

I'm creating anonymous block, which takes data from `orders` (`source`) and inserts it into the `order_shipments` (`dest`).

Comment: Can show What did you try ?

Comment: Could you provide ENTIRE table schema of `source` ?

Comment: please, can you bring your tables DDL ? by using `\d order_shipments;` and `\d orders;` and give your postgreSQL version using `SELECT version();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found rather simple solution.

Thanks to the to the question [Insert data and set foreign keys with Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391090/insert-data-and-set-foreign-keys-with-postgres)

The result is

```
with i as (
    insert into order_shipments (order_id, method_id, deliver_at, barcode, sent_at, city_id, subway_id)
    select o.id, o.shipment_method_id, o.courier_deliver_at, o.barcode, o.sent_at, o.courier_city_id, o.courier_subway_id
    from orders o
    returning id
)
update orders o
set current_shipment_id = i.id
from i;
```