# Postgres: How do I insert from another table and set a foreign key to the row afterwards?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to migrate my database structure and extract some fields in other tables.

I have a table orders:

```
+---------+--------------+------------+
| orderId | shipmentcost | shipmentId |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| 1       | 9.9          |null        |
| 2       | 4.9          |null        |
+---------+--------------+------------+
```

in which I just added `shipmentcost.shipmentId` so I can create a new table `shipments`:

```
+------------+--------------+
| shipmentId | shipmentcost |
+------------+--------------+
```

This table is empty and you can probably guess I want to connect it to `orders` and fill it with the data now included in `orders` so I can delete the column `orders.shipmentcost`

The result of the query should be:

```
+---------+--------------+------------+
| orderId | shipmentcost | shipmentId |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| 1       | 9.9          |1           |
| 2       | 4.9          |2           |
+---------+--------------+------------+

+------------+--------------+
| shipmentId | shipmentcost |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | 9.9          |
| 2          | 4.9          |
+------------+--------------+
```

Both `orders.orderId` and `shipment.shipmentId` are the primary key and filled with the sequences `orders_orderId_seq` as `shipments_shipmentId_seq`

So how do I achieve inserting the data of `orders` into `shipments` while updating `orders.shipmentId`?

I am using PostgeSQL 9.2, although it would be appreciated if the solution is compatible with other Postgres versions as well

Comment: Does this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7391090/1679863 help?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because `shipmentcost` is not unique. But thanks anyhow, this is the answer I found before that came nearest to a solution. Adding `orderId` as a temporary column did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporarily add the `orderId` column to `shippments`:

```
alter table shippments
add column orderId integer;
```

Insert into it using the returned `orderId` to update the `orders` table

```
with i as (
    insert into shippments (shippmentcost, orderId)
    select shippementcost, orderId
    from orders
    returning shippementId, orderId
)
update orders o
set shippmentId = i.shippmentId
from i
where i.orderId = o.orderId
;
```

Drop the temporary column:

```
alter table shippments drop column orderId;
```

And the now unnecessary `orders.shippmentCost` column:

```
alter table orders drop column shippmentCost;
```