# Return data from subselect used in INSERT in a Common Table Expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, data-migration, postgresql-10

I am trying to move `bytea` data from one table to another, updating references in one query.

Therefore I would like to return data from the query used for the insert that is not used for the insert.

```
INSERT INTO file_data (data)
  select image from task_log where image is not null
RETURNING id as file_data_id, task_log.id as task_log_id
```

But I get an error for that query:

> ```
> [42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "task_log"
> ```

I want to do something like:

```
WITH inserted AS (
  INSERT INTO file_data (data)
    SELECT image FROM task_log WHERE image IS NOT NULL
  RETURNING id AS file_data_id, task_log.id AS task_log_id
)
UPDATE task_log
SET    task_log.attachment_id = inserted.file_data_id,
       task_log.attachment_type = 'INLINE_IMAGE'
FROM   inserted
WHERE  inserted.task_log_id = task_log.id;
```

But I fail to get all data used for the insert, I can't return the id from the subselect.

I was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10150791/510711) answer on how to do that with [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) but I can't find a way to make it work.

Comment: remove the table-alias for the *L-value* in UPDATE statements: `SET    task_log.attachment_id = ...` -->> `SET    attachment_id = ...` , etc

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes! Thanks for your help :-) I posted my solution as an answer as I resorted to add a temp column to keep the duplicates. If you wish you (or I) can add it to your answer to keep one single answer with all those possible solutions.

Comment: Your separate answer is just fine. And I would not want this course of action in my answer anyway. Performance is much worse than for the method using a serial number I proposed in the linked answer. Adding & removing a column require's owner's privileges, a full table rewrite and  exclusive locks on the table, which is poison for concurrent access. :)

Comment: Hehe, ok, I added that as a warning to my answer, citing your words. Hope that is Ok :-)

Comment: That's perfect. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to get your table names and aliases right. Plus, the connection between the two tables is the column `image` (`data`in the new table `file_data`):

```
WITH inserted AS (
  INSERT INTO file_data (data)
  SELECT image
  FROM   task_log
  WHERE  image IS NOT NULL
  RETURNING id, data  -- can only reference target row
)
UPDATE task_log t
SET    attachment_id = i.id
     , attachment_type = 'INLINE_IMAGE'
FROM   inserted i
WHERE  t.image = i.data;
```

Like explained in my old answer you referenced, `image` must be unique in `task_log` for this to work:

- [Insert data and set foreign keys with Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391090/insert-data-and-set-foreign-keys-with-postgres/10150791#10150791)

I added a technique how to disambiguate non-unique values in the referenced answer. Not sure if you'd want duplicate images in `file_data`, though.

In the `RETURNING` clause of an `INSERT` you can only reference columns from the inserted row. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

> The optional `RETURNING` clause causes `INSERT` to compute and return
>   value(s) based on each row actually inserted  (...) However, **any
>   expression using the table's columns is allowed**.

Bold emphasis mine.

#### Fold duplicate source values

If you want distinct entries in the target table of the `INSERT` (`task_log`), all you need in this case is `DISTINCT` in the initial `SELECT`:

```
WITH inserted AS (
  INSERT INTO file_data (data)
  SELECT DISTINCT image  -- fold duplicates
  FROM   task_log
  WHERE  image IS NOT NULL
  RETURNING id, data  -- can only reference target row
)
UPDATE task_log t
SET    attachment_id = i.id
     , attachment_type = 'INLINE_IMAGE'
FROM   inserted i
WHERE  t.image = i.data;
```

The resulting `file_data.id` is used multiple times in `task_log`. Be aware that multiple rows in `task_log` now point to the same image in `file_data`. Careful with updates and deletes ...

Comment: So it's not possible to piggy back the task_log.id onto the result from the insert?

Comment: Not out of the box. I added more.

Comment: The images are not unique but I am trying to reference them individually.. I tried your other example with row_number, but I don't know what you eat for breakfast to get your brain up to that insight into postgres :-)

Comment: If I use your updated query I think I should add a `select **distinct** image from task_log` to not add not used entries. ?

Comment: @flob: Yes, to fold dupes, `DISTINCT` (or `GROUP BY`) in the initial `SELECT` is all you need. Be aware of implications, though. I added more.

Comment: Great :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am currently trying to avoid that complications by adding a temp column and removing it in the same transaction, I don't know how the implications might be for a big db but as ours is quite small (less than 20k images).  `alter table file_data add column task_log_id bigint;` before, adding that id in the insert `INSERT INTO file_data (data, task_log_id) select image, id from task_log where image is not null` and then using it in the update `where inserted.task_log_id = task_log.id;`. It works but has a quite bad smell ... :-/

Comment: @flob: Start by getting the requirements straight: Do you want to allow duplicate values of `data` in `file_data`? I.e.: do you want to store images redundantly if used in multiple rows in `task_log`? Typically, the answer is *no*, in which case you have to fold dupes. Plus you might need to do more to avoid dupes between newly inserted and existing rows in `file_data`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30878260/939860

Comment: For now I need those duplicates due to the application but later I should add deduplication :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to **replicate duplicates** so I ended up **adding a temp column** for the id of the used data row.

```
alter table file_data add column task_log_id bigint;
-- insert & update data
alter table file_data drop column task_log_id;
```

The full move script was

```
-- A new table for any file data
CREATE TABLE file_data (
  id         BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data  bytea
);

-- Move data from task_log to bytes

-- Create new columns to reference file_data
alter table task_log add column attachment_type VARCHAR(50);
alter table task_log add column attachment_id bigint REFERENCES file_data;

-- add a temp column for the task_id used for the insert
alter table file_data add column task_log_id bigint;

-- insert data into file_data and set references
with inserted as (
  INSERT INTO file_data (data, task_log_id)
    select image, id from task_log where image is not null
  RETURNING id, task_log_id
)
UPDATE task_log
SET   attachment_id = inserted.id,
      attachment_type = 'INLINE_IMAGE'
FROM  inserted
where inserted.task_log_id = task_log.id;
-- delete the temp column
alter table file_data drop column task_log_id;
-- delete task_log images
alter table task_log drop column image;
```

As this produces some dead data I ran a `vacuum full` afterwards to clean up.

But please let me repeat the warning from @ErwinBrandstetter:

> Performance is much worse than for the method using a serial number I proposed in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10150791/510711). Adding & removing a column require's owner's privileges, a full table rewrite and exclusive locks on the table, which is poison for concurrent access.